# JSON stringify and use of \

Tags: javascript

```
assert(JSON.stringify(searchForMatches(searchData,['cats']))==='["catcode.io","catgifs.co"]',"The result should be '[\"catcode.io\",\"catgifs.co\"]'");
```

Why do I need the use of \ at the end multiple times? It throws an error otherwise. Is it specific to JSON.stringify and/or when/how should I go about about using it in future instances?

Comment: \ is signifying you are escaping characters.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash is a JavaScript operator used within a string for escaping a special character.
In your case it is escaping a quotation.  See this example:

```
// in this case it escapes the " symbol because that would end the string.
var x = "\"";
```

This is the same as:

```
// in this case you don't need to escape it because 
//   the string begins with the apostrophe instead of the " character
var x = '"';
```

In both cases **console.log(x);** will print a single quote character.

Answer (score 1):

`\` is an escape operator. It prevents the language from parsing the next char as syntax relevant, so without it your string stops at the next `"` after the first `"` which starts the string.